# How to skip a test-case file from executing for a particular browser in Protractor

Tags: selenium, jasmine, protractor, e2e-testing, angular-e2e

I am using **Protractor** for writing e2e test cases in Angular using **Jasmin**.

I am using **Saucelab** for executing my test cases on **Chrome, Firefox, Edge and IE11**.

I came across a issue that **hover** functionality using **mouseMove** doesen't work in case of IE11 so i want to **skip** those test-cases for **IE11** but thost test must execute for rest 3 browsers.

My protractor.config.js file as below
    ...
    ...

```
     multiCapabilities: ([
        {
           name: "ds-e2e-firefox",
           browserName: "firefox",
           version: "63"
        },
        {
           name: "ds-e2e-chrome",
           browserName: "googlechrome",
           version: "70"
        },
        {
           name: "ds-e2e-edge",
           browserName: "MicrosoftEdge",
           version: "16",
           avoidProxy: true
        },
        {
          name: "ds-e2e-ie11",
          browserName: "internet explorer",
          version: "11",
          iedriverVersion: "3.12.0"
        }
      ]).map(cap => Object.assign(cap, {
        platform: "Windows 10",
        seleniumVersion: SELENIUM_VERSION,
        screenResolution: "1920x1080"
      }))
    };
...
```

I am open with some other workaround as i am unable to think how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

multicapabilities is collection which takes array of capability so you Can try with exclude keyword reserved for ignoring spec files.

```
    {
      name: "ds-e2e-ie11",
      browserName: "internet explorer",
      version: "11",
      iedriverVersion: "3.12.0",
      exclude: [specfile.js, specfile2.js]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to approach it is this way

```
it("Search by name", async () => {

    // open home page
    await browser.get(params.baseUrl);

    let capabilities = await browser.getCapabilities();
    let browserName = capabilities.map_.get('browserName');

    if (browserName === "chrome") {
        // your test goes here
    }
});
```